equidistribution of subsequences of equidistributed sequences
Let $a_n$ be a sequence such that $a_n \mod 1$ equidistributes in a subinterval [a,b)$\subseteq [0,1)$. Then it follows that for any $k\neq 0$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N e^{2\pi i k a_n}\to \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b e^{2i \pi kx}dx$$
I would like to see what happens for subsequences $b_n=a_{c+Mn}$ for M fixed. I am guessing it should also equidistribute on $[a,b)$ but not sure why.

Nice question.  With the displayed equation you wrote, you might want to say "for every integer $k$" instead of "for any $k\neq 0$" (although the statement you made is probably also correct).
There are counterexamples to your guess: if $a_{2n}$ equidistributes in $[0,1/2)$ and $a_{2n+1}$ equidistributes in $[1/2,1)$ then $a_n$ equidistributes in $[0,1)$.  But $a_{2n}$ cannot equidistribute in $[0,1)$, being trapped in $[0,1/2)$.
